# Push Segue Not Loading Destination View Controller Visibly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a view controller embedded in a navigation controller where I want to perform a push segue to reach another view controller. When I call

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueStudy" sender:self];`

I know the push segue does get called as prepareForSegue gets called properly. I'm also sure that the destination view controller is embedded in the navigation controller. I know that the destination view controller's view is loading as I've outputted

`NSLog(@"View loaded");`

in the destination view controller's viewDidLoad method and it is being called properly. However, although viewDidLoad is being called in the destination view controller, the view isn't loading visibly and the push segue isn't happening visibly. The segue does occur and viewDidLoad is called in the destination view controller, but the view controller doesn't load visibly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The source view controller should be embedded in a navigation controller, not the destination view controller.

Comment: Sorry about that. The source view controller is embedded in the navigation controller

Comment: Well, then, it's hard to say what's wrong. I can't see how viewDidLoad would be called but the view not show up. Are you doing anything in the pushed controller's viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear, that would cause it to disappear.

Comment: Does viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear get called?

Comment: Neither viewWillAppear nor viewDidAppear get called, though viewDidLoad does get called. I also don't believe there's anything in viewDidLoad that would cause the view to not appear properly.